# Change post date on a WordPress post

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to edit the post date on a WordPress post to show a future date is this possible? For example:
Show that post was published on 6/06/10 but I actually posted it today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer. It was a plugin called back to the future.

Answer (score 1):

Using Wordpress 2.8.1, I was able to edit the publish date to a future date.  Upon saving, the verbiage changed from "Published on" to "Schedule for" which implies that you can schedule posts to publish on a specified date.

Comment: hmm is it possible to roll back the clock on wordpress. where does it pull its time from?

Answer (score 1):

You can schedule the post from from your admin panel, right hand side you have a option named as "PUBLISH" underneath this you have all option of publishing post.

See the attached file here...[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you simply put in the date that you want it to be, while the post status is on draft, press ok, and then the publish button should turn into a schedule button.

If it doesn't, save the post and go to where all the posts are listed, set the date there, and set it to published. It should then turn into a scheduled post.

It this still doesn't work, you might want to copy and paste the contents into a new post and start over from there.

Comment: I don't want it to be scheduled I want the actual date to show up to be in the future when i post it.